# AdSense saying that ads.txt file is missing

Tags: ads, adsense

AdSense is telling me that the ads.txt file which I have uploaded is missing although it is there: https://matcha.red/ads.txt
The file is accessible both via www and without and both via https and http.
Does anybody know what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine. Your ads.txt file is OK.
It's an error on Google. Do not worry.